# libclang ,clang_Cursor_isAnonymous what is an anonymous declaration?

Tags: c, llvm-clang, libclang

I have some difficulties to understand what are anonymous structures declaration (or union) .

From this link:
    http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecordDecl.html#ad2dd151523eecb8d15149cc0937c3dff

**this is an anonymous declaration**

```
union { int i; float f; };
```

and not this

```
union X { int i; float f; };
union { int i; float f; } obj;
```

**But** if I make some tests:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "clang-c/Index.h"
/*
compile with:
clang -lclang -o anonymous_record_decl_check anonymous_record_decl_check.c
*/
static enum CXChildVisitResult 
visitor(CXCursor cursor, CXCursor parent, CXClientData data)
{
  CXSourceLocation loc;
  CXFile file;
  unsigned line;
  unsigned column;
  unsigned offset;
  if (clang_getCursorKind(cursor) == CXCursor_StructDecl)
  {
    printf("sentinel %d\n", __LINE__);
    loc = clang_getCursorLocation(cursor);
    clang_getSpellingLocation(loc,
                              &file,
                              &line,
                              &column,
                              &offset);

    printf("sentinel %d\n", __LINE__);
    printf("line: %d anon ? %d\n", line, clang_Cursor_isAnonymous(cursor));
  }

  if (clang_getCursorKind(cursor) == CXCursor_UnionDecl)
  {
    printf("sentinel %d\n", __LINE__);
    loc = clang_getCursorLocation(cursor);
    printf("sentinel %d\n", __LINE__);
    clang_getSpellingLocation(loc,
                              &file,
                              &line,
                              &column,
                              &offset);
    printf("line: %d anon ? %d\n", line, clang_Cursor_isAnonymous(cursor));
  }
  return CXChildVisit_Recurse; // visit complete AST recursivly
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  CXIndex Index = clang_createIndex(0, 1);
  CXTranslationUnit TU = clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile(Index,
                                                      "record_decls.c",
                                                      0,
                                                      0,
                                                      0,
                                                      0);

  clang_visitChildren(clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(TU), visitor, 0);

  clang_disposeTranslationUnit(TU);
  clang_disposeIndex(Index);
  return 0;
}
```

with the file that is parsed ( record_decls.c ):

```
struct { int a; char b; };
struct tata { int c; double e;};
union { int i; float f; };
union X { int i; float f; };
```

I have this output:

```
sentinel 17
sentinel 25
line: 1 anon ? 0
sentinel 17
sentinel 25
line: 2 anon ? 0
sentinel 31
sentinel 33
line: 3 anon ? 0
sentinel 31
sentinel 33
line: 4 anon ? 0
```

Which means that all my declarations return the same value form `clang_Cursor_isAnonymous`

Which means well I don't really know here is the comments from the headers:

```
/**
 * \brief Determine whether the given cursor represents an anonymous record
 * declaration.
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple, anonymous structures or unions are c++ features so :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "clang-c/Index.h"
/*
compile with:
clang -lclang -o anonymous_record_decl_check anonymous_record_decl_check.c
*/
static enum CXChildVisitResult 
visitor(CXCursor cursor, CXCursor parent, CXClientData data)
{
  CXSourceLocation loc;
  CXFile file;
  unsigned line;
  unsigned column;
  unsigned offset;
  if (clang_getCursorKind(cursor) == CXCursor_StructDecl)
  {
    printf("sentinel %d\n", __LINE__);
    loc = clang_getCursorLocation(cursor);
    clang_getSpellingLocation(loc,
                              &file,
                              &line,
                              &column,
                              &offset);

    printf("sentinel %d\n", __LINE__);
    printf("line: %d anon ? %d\n", line, clang_Cursor_isAnonymous(cursor));
  }

  if (clang_getCursorKind(cursor) == CXCursor_UnionDecl)
  {
    printf("sentinel %d\n", __LINE__);
    loc = clang_getCursorLocation(cursor);
    printf("sentinel %d\n", __LINE__);
    clang_getSpellingLocation(loc,
                              &file,
                              &line,
                              &column,
                              &offset);
    printf("line: %d anon ? %d\n", line, clang_Cursor_isAnonymous(cursor));
  }
  return CXChildVisit_Recurse; // visit complete AST recursivly
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  CXIndex Index = clang_createIndex(0, 1);
  const char *args[] = { "-x", "c++" };
  CXTranslationUnit TU = clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile(Index,
                                                      "record_decls.c",
                                                      2,
                                                      args,
                                                      0,
                                                      0);

  clang_visitChildren(clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(TU), visitor, 0);

  clang_disposeTranslationUnit(TU);
  clang_disposeIndex(Index);
  return 0;
}
```